# How do I use bazel to produce multiple files from the same set of input files

Tags: bazel

I have a simple project which uses [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to make a small C++ library available to C#. The C++ part is a single source and a single header file -- in addition there is one SWIG interface file. The output from SWIG consists of 5 C# source files and 1 C++ source file.

Doing this with `make` is fairly simple, but I'm having a few problems wrapping my head around bazel.

How can I tell bazel that those 6 files are *all* generated using the same command? Also, while I'm at it, how I do I tell bazel to actually invoke that command.

The end product, that I'm ultimately interested in, is a .net dll file which only depend on the interface file and the original C++ header file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bazel doesn't have a built-in rule to generate SWIG from C++, but you can either use a general-purpose rule ([`genrule`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule)) or teach Bazel how to build a SWIG library by [writing your own rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html).

If you use a `genrule`, you specify all the expected outputs in the `outs` attribute. Your rule will look something like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "cc_swig",
    srcs = [
        "lib.cc",
        "lib.h",
    ],
    outs = [
        "file1.cs",
        ...
        "fileN.cc",
    ],
    tools = [
        "//path/to/swig/compiler:bin",
    ],
    cmd = "$(location //path/to/swig/compiler:bin) --src=$(location lib.cc) --header=$(location lib.h) --out1=$(location file1.cs) ... --outN=$(location fileN.cc)",
)
```

The `$(location)` construct in `cmd` is a required placeholder, Bazel replaces those with the run-time path of the referenced file.

(If the SWIG compiler won't let you specify where to put its outputs, you can add more commands to `cmd` that `mv` the output files to their final location, e.g. `cmd = "... && mv outputs/lib.cs $(location file1.cs)"`.)

Writing your own rules is more advanced so I won't describe that here, you can read about them [in the docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html#macros-and-rules).

On how to get Bazel to build the library -- if the SWIG-compiling rule is a dependency of your top-level target (i.e. whatever you "bazel build"), then Bazel will build it. See for example [the Getting started guide, on how to build a C++ project](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html#build-with-bazel).

Comment: I almost got this working, except I need a way to get the directory that my output files are supposed to be generated in; `$(location file1.cs)`, except something more like `$(dir file1.cs)`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Sure, Bazel expands the whole `$(location)` expression to a simple string before executing the command, meaning you can just use `$$(dirname $(location file1.cs))`. You need `$$` in order to escape `$` for the `genrule.cmd` command; Bazel will replace the whole thing with `$(dirname bazel-out/some/path/file1.cs)` and that's the Shell command it will ultimately execute.

Comment: You can debug this using `echo "$(location file1.cs)"`. Do not, however, hardcode the resulting string -- the result of `$(location foo)` can vary from build to build; always use `$(location)` (or `$(locations)`) to retrieve the path of files in `srcs`, `outs`, and `tools`.